# Opening terminal on second monitor by default

Tags: multiple-monitors, terminal, visual-studio-2015

Is there a way for the terminal to be opened on the second screen when running a program through Visual Studio 2015? Right now I have my graphical window and my terminal opening on the main screen where VS is opened. However when I want to look at the output in the terminal and the graphical window at the same time, I always have to move the terminal to my second screen.

Comment: What windows version do you use and what do you use as terminal server interface?

Comment: @LPChip: I have Windows 10. What do you mean by terminal server interface? I haven't installed anything special.

Comment: So... Remote Desktop I assume?

Comment: @LPChip: I am working on my local machine. Sorry, I don't understand what you're on to!

Comment: My bad. I referred to terminal as connecting to a remote machine, but you mean command prompt window aren't you?

Comment: @LPChip: Yes, sorry, in Linux it's called terminal that's why I thought in Windows it would be too.